# Set content align in context of setHgrow

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm using JavaFX-8 to build an application. I'm trying to build an menue. Each menu item is a `ToggleButton` all the `ToggleButtons` should have the same width. So I used following code snipped:

```
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        ToggleButton toggleButton = new ToggleButton("MyText");
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.getChildren().add(toggleButton);
        HBox.setHgrow(toggleButton, Priority.ALWAYS);
        toggleButton.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                            [...]
        vbox.getChildren().add(hBox,hbox2,hbox3,...);
```

**Result:**

[image: snipped of the result of the shown code]

The width of each item is now the same, but the text alignment seems to be centred now. I tried to change the alignment to `LEFT` by `toggleButton.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT)` and `toggleButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT)` but without success. Is there an other way to solve this problem?

**Update:**
I tried `toggleButton.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);` having the same result as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various mechanisms for controlling alignment in `Labeled` and its subclasses:

The [alignmentProperty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#alignmentProperty) is the one you want here. According to the documentation, it:

> Specifies how the text and graphic within the Labeled should be
>   aligned when there is empty space within the Labeled.

So you just need

```
toggleButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
```

The [textAlignmentProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textAlignmentProperty)

> Specifies the behavior for lines of text when text is multiline Unlike
>   contentDisplayProperty() which affects the graphic and text, this
>   setting only affects multiple lines of text relative to the text
>   bounds.

In other words, if you have multiple lines of text, you can think of the entire text as taking up a rectangle whose height is bounded by all the lines and whose width is bounded by the widest line. The `textAlignment` property specifies how *each line* is aligned within that rectangle. That doesn't apply in your case, since you only have one line of text.

Finally, there is the [`contentDisplayProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#contentDisplayProperty--). This

> Specifies the positioning of the graphic relative to the text.

and so only makes a difference if you have both text and graphic displayed in the button. Setting it to `ContentDisplay.LEFT` specifies that the graphic should be placed to the left of the text, for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot: toggleButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT); was the solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
ToggleButton toggleButton = new ToggleButton("MyText");
HBox hBox = new HBox();
hBox.getChildren().add(toggleButton);
HBox.setHgrow(toggleButton, Priority.ALWAYS);
toggleButton.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
toggleButton.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);//set text align
```

See JavaDoc ToggleButton :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html
and TextAlignment http://download.java.net/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/text/TextAlignment.html#LEFT

**Option II**
Using JavaFX style sheet

```
.toggle-button1{
    -fx-font: 30 arial; 
    -fx-text-alignment: left;   
}
```

In Java

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("myStyle.css");//load css
toggleButton.getStyleClass().add("toggle-button1");// assign style
```

Comment: It has been a while for me, progging JavaFX. But I thought there was something like `redraw`, `invalidate` to call after a GUI update is made... (looking for it now, not finding it yet),,, after your update, my answer looks stupid :(

Comment: @HW90 how about a css?

Comment: @Danielson there are no `redraw` or `invalidate` methods in JavaFX similar to the ones you are looking for. The scene will repaint automatically if you change the properties.

Comment: Tried my **option 2**?

Comment: `textAlignment` is the wrong property (see the documentation); so it doesn't really matter if you set it in Java code or in CSS.

Comment: @Danielson: Yes tried it, but it does not change anything